# Binding div if function return true

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js

How to bind element only if the function return true;

```
<label class="hello" data-bind="if: myFunction">Hello World</label>

function myFunction(n){
    if(n==2) return true;
}
```

it is visible also function return false

Comment: Is this issue resolved or are you still having trouble getting it to work?

Comment: i resolved the problem with visible-binding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `if` binding applies to the content of the element. If you want the element itself to disappear rather than just the text within it you'll need to wrap the label inside of something else and apply the binding to the wrapper. You can also use the virtual binding for this.

```
<--ko if: myFunction-->
<label class="hello">Hello World</label>
<!--/ko-->
```

Additionally, for your function to update properly it will have to be a computed property rather than a normal function, and `n` needs to be an observable.

```
var n = ko.observable();
myFunction = ko.computed(function(){
    if(n()==2) return true;
});
```